# Unit Testing RecyclerView OnItemTouchListener Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-recyclerview, robolectric

So after calling this onto my tests to layout the recyclerview:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(listener);
recyclerView.measure(0, 0); 
recyclerView.layout(0, 0, 100, 10000);
```

and my `OnItemTouchListener` being:

```
listener = new RecyclerOnTouchListener(this, new RecyclerOnTouchListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Sample toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

and I want to assert:

```
Assertions.assertThat(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("Sample Toast");
```

I need to simulate item clicks on the recyclerview. And what i'm doing is this:

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.performClick();
recyclerView.performClick()
```

and they both return false, meaning no onclick listener in them is being called.

So how do we really test `OnItemTouchListener` in recyclerview? In Robolectric?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue that was fixed by adding the line before setAdapter:

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run in to the same problem and while I haven't found any good solution to the problem, I have a workaround that at least makes testing possible until I can find something better.

One thing you can do is to create a method in your activity and have the onClick listener call that directly.

```
void recyclerOnClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

void addTouchListener() {
    RecyclerOnTouchListener touchListener = new RecyclerOnTouchListener(this, recyclerView,
            new RecyclerOnTouchListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NotNull View view, int position) {
                    recyclerOnClick(view, position);
                }
            });
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(touchListener)
}
```

Then in your tests you can just call `adapter.recyclerOnClick()` for the view you want to simulate the click on.